# Applications of k-medians with moment constraints

Tags: geometry, oc.optimization-and-control

Suppose I have a collection of points $p_1,\dots,p_N$ in the plane.  In the *Euclidean $k$-medians* (or *$k$-means*) problems, our objective is to distribute a set of $k$ points $x_1,\dots,x_k$ in the plane so as to minimize the distances (or squares of distances) to the points $p_i$, i.e. to minimize the quantity $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \min_j \| x_j - p_i \|$ (I am not requiring that the $x_j$'s be a subset of the $p_i$'s; they can lie anywhere in the plane).  Obviously this problem has many practical applications.

My question is:  let's suppose we impose some constraints on the first or second moments of $x_1,\dots,x_k$, i.e. require that $\frac{1}{k}\sum_j x_j = x_0$ for some fixed point $x_0$, or that $\frac{1}{k} \sum_j \|x_j - \bar{x}\|^2 \leq S^2$ for some given threshold $S^2$.  Is there any conceivable practical scenario where this might arise?

I am not asking for assistance in solving this problem -- I'm really just interested in any thoughts on contexts where it might occur.